# How to show a subset doesn't span a space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, vectors

Given that $\{v_1,…,v_m\}$ is linearly independent, how do you show that $\{v_2,…,v_m\}$ does not span that same vector space?

Comment: Hint: Can $v_1$ be in the span of $v_2,\dots,v_m$?

Comment: I'm confused about how to write the proof still. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: What does it mean to be linearly independent? What does it mean for $v_1$ to be in the span of $v_2,\dots,v_m$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Clearly $v_1 \not \in span \{v_2, \ldots, v_m\}$

Comment: Can you please explain further? @gt6989b

Comment: This is an example of something on the span of the first set that is not on the span of the second set. Thus, the second span must be included in the first but the first is larger